# is there anyway to bind non HTML tags like v-btn to Nuxt's tag prop

Tags: vue.js, tags, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

So this is the code i type on my editor

```
<nuxt-link :to="www.test.com" tag="v-btn" /> Link Button </nuxt-link>
```

apparently v-btn is not an HTML original tag but a vuetify specific one and when i write the code this way it doesn't actually work and i'm not getting the styles that are bind with a v-btn tag.
so i'm wondering if there's actually a way to do this...

ps: wrapping the v-btn with a nuxt-link tag in this way below

```
<nuxt-link to="www.text.com">
     <v-btn>Link Button</v-btn> 
</nuxt-link>
```

makes the button a link and actually works but this can't be used everywhere since some of the vuetify tags are related together and adding non vuetify tags inside it ruins the styles, like this example below which is a case of using a v-btn inside a v-toolbar-item, normally v-btn has a special style inside a v-toolbar-item but when we wrap it with a nuxt-link it loses all the styles.

```
      <v-toolbar-items>
      <nuxt-link :to="www.test.com>
        <v-btn>Link Button</v-btn>
      </nuxt-link>
      </v-toolbar-items>
```

Comment: We can not write: `:to="www.test.com"`, we must point to a route link there, not to a URL address

Comment: i know that.... that's just for showing purpose not related to the question

Answer (score 1):

The `v-btn` component from Vuetify has a `nuxt` property to handle Nuxt.js:

```html
<v-btn nuxt to="www.text.com">Link Button</v-btn>
```

See vuetify docs about the "nuxt" property: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons/#api

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `href="string"`

```
<template>
  <v-col class="pb-0">
    <v-btn
      v-for="(link, i) in links"
      :key="i"
      depressed
      color=""
      text
      rounded
      class="text-none"
      :to="link.l"
      :href="link.href"
    >
      {{ link.n }}
    </v-btn>
  </v-col>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      links: [
        {
          n: 'About us',
          l: '/about-us'
        },
        {
          n: 'Help',
          l: '/help'
        },
        {
          n: 'Blog',
          l: '/blog'
        },
        {
          n: 'Contact',
          l: '/contact'
        },
        {
          n: 'google.com',
          href: 'https://www.google.com'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

</script>
```